# IF Formula, Within 90 days condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula which works off two tables. The formula reads the company name in the same row (Column B, in this case row 22), and does a vlookup in another table to find a match. It then looks for the word 'Won' in column Z of the same row, and then if the date in column AH is within 90 days.

If both are true, it should return 'Trading', if it returns 'Won' but the date is over 90 days, it should return 'Dormant', and if 'Won' isn't found, it should return 'Potential'.

However it's not picking up the date correctly, as changing the date under or over 90 days doesn't change the output. I'm also unsure on the best way to make it equal 'potential' for names it can't find or names that don't equal 'won'. Here's the formula:

```
=IF(AND(LOOKUP(2,1/(KPI!$A$1:$A$14266=""&TEXT(B22,0)&""),KPI!$Z$1:$Z$14266)="Won",LOOKUP(2,1/(KPI!$A$1:$A$14266=""&TEXT(B22,0)&""),KPI!$AH$1:$AH$14266)-TODAY()<=90),"Trading",IF(AND(AND(LOOKUP(2,1/(KPI!$A$1:$A$14266=""&TEXT(B22,0)&""),KPI!$Z$1:$Z$14266)="Won",LOOKUP(2,1/(KPI!$A$1:$A$14266=""&TEXT(B22,0)&""),KPI!$AH$1:$AH$14266)-TODAY()>90)),"Dormant","Potential"))
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to give some sample data or a screenshot of the data you are working with?

Comment: Dates in Excel are tricky. Are the dates in your data real Excel dates, or are these text fields ?

Comment: are the dates supposed to be in the future or in the past? As you have "Won" there I assume they should be in the past, but then your LOOKUP(...)-TODAY()>90 is wrong as it only gets positive value if your lookup date is in the future so only returns TRUE if the date lookuped is after 18.3.2019 in case of today which I am not sure is your intention. As @JoeJam correctly stated it would help to have a sample.